# Visual Studio 2010 problem with .Net T4 - Host.LoadIncludeText not interpreting code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, t4

We have app.config files for deployment to 8 different environments e.g Dev, Local, Test, UAT, Prod etc. To make changes easier, each top level .tt looks like this:

e.g.

### app.dev.tt

```
<#
    EnvironmentName = @"Dev";
#>
<#@ include file="CommonTemplate.ttinclude" #>
```

### The CommonTemplate.ttinclude includes:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension="config" #>
<#@ include file="..\MasterConfig\MasterConfig.ttinclude" #>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   ...
</configuration>
```

### The MasterConfig.ttinclude has something like this:

```
   <#
        string hostPath = this.Host.ResolvePath("..\MasterConfig");
        string EnvironmentIncludePath = string.Format(@"{0}\EnvironmentSettings\{1}.ttinclude", hostPath, EnvironmentName);

        EnvironmentIncludePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(EnvironmentIncludePath);
        string context = null;
        string resolvedName = null;
        Host.LoadIncludeText(EnvironmentIncludePath, out context, out resolvedName);

        public string ServicesMachineName = "";
```

Basically it looks for a file named MasterConfig\EnvironmentSettings\Dev.ttinclude and dynamically includes it.

### and the contents of Dev.ttinclude looks like:

```
<#
    ServicesMachineName = "SOMESERVERNAME";
        ... [snip other setting specific stuff stuff]
#>
```

Although it all seems to work (and worked on VS 2008) the problem is that the code in Dev.ttinclude is not executed so ServicesMachineName is never set.

### Current workaround:

This works, but is not elegant or as dynamic as the other solution, but we cannot figure out why LoadIncludeText no longer works since migrating from VS 2008.

```
switch(EnvironmentName.ToUpper().Trim())
    {
        case "DEV":
            #><#@ include file="..\MasterConfig\EnvironmentSettings\Dev.ttinclude" #><#
            break;
        case "LOCAL":
            #><#@ include file="..\MasterConfig\EnvironmentSettings\Local.ttinclude" #><#
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Error the specified Environment Name was not found");
    }
```

### Question:

**Are we doing something wrong with Host.LoadIncludeText or has functionality changed between VS 2008 and VS 2010?**